# Ubuntu : rails server fails to execute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

Ubuntu 12.04

When I execute:
rails server

I get some information that seems to contradict itself (1.9.3 and 1.8.7?)

```
/home/byoung/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/pg-0.13.2/lib/pg_ext.so: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]

ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]

sudo ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
```

sudo rails server starts up just fine but is running version 1.8.7

**EDIT** Yes I have RVM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change over to sudo, you are leaving your shell, where RVM has setup shop. In your shell, it's using 1.9.3, but in sudo land, it's using the default 1.8.7

In general: don't use sudo with rvm.